# Can't render Google Visualizations ChartWrapper

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Hey stackoverflow community,
I'm trying to render a Column Chart using google.visualizations.ChartWrapper but   I am unable to get the following javascript code to work:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart','controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);    
function drawDashboard() {   
var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Element');
data.addColumn('number', 'FillRate');
data.addRows([['Tank11Chocolate', 100.0],['Tank20Gold', 50.0]]);
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({'chartType': 'ColumnChart','containerId': 'colChart','dataTable': data});        
chart.draw();
}
```

Could someone with perhaps more knowledge of Google Visualizations or javascript help me out please?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what your script should do, and what are the results you are getting right now.

Comment: It's supposed to render a column chart with two columns in it, but I'm just getting a blank page

Comment: Thank you, but it ended up just being a newbie mistake. Thanks for stopping by anyway :)

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem on your own. I'm not familiar with `google-visualization`, so I just wanted to point you out that it's important to share those details when you post questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's possible to stare at code for hours and still not realize that I forgot to write new when I created my DataTable object. Problem solved!